# Rails 4: How to use Store (serialized stored hash) in Where?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, serialization, hash, store

I'm using Rails4's Store feature. I've added a new stored attributes namely "friends" with four accessors, first ... fourth.

The problem is how to utilize it in the "where" condition. When I use it as:

```
@persons = Person.where(friends.has_value?@user.id)
```

I receive this error:

```
NameError in UsersController#myfrineds
undefined local variable or method `friends'
```

I tried some other different ways but still I get error. Could you please help me to solve it? Or please let me know if you have any better idea to implement it (storing a dynamic hash of key/values)?

Answer (score 1):

As stated by **Uzbekjon**, **store** is not made for this kind of things. Some workarounds to your problem:

- Use a custom query (would be quite slow depending on table size so be careful):

  ```
  @persons = Person.where('friends LIKE ? OR friends LIKE ? OR friends LIKE ? OR friends LIKE ?', "%first: #{@person.id}\n%", "%second: #{@person.id}\n%", "%third: #{@person.id}\n%", "%fourth: #{@person.id}\n%")
  ```

  This assumes you used **yaml** for the serialization of `friends` attribute (it's the default). If you used **json** you'll have to change the query accordingly.
- If you're using PostgreSQL you can use **array** attribute instead of **store**. Queries would have better timings since PostgreSQL supports this datatype.

  Migration:

  ```
  def change
    add_column :people, :friends, :text, array: true, default: []

    # if you want to add index:
    add_index  :people, :friends, using: 'gin'
  end
  ```

  Creation of records:

  ```
  Person.create(..., friends: [friend_id_1, friend_id_2, friend_id_3, friend_id_4])
  ```

  Query:

  ```
  @persons = Person.where('? = ANY(friends)', @person.id)
  ```

  You may also need to add to your **Gemfile**:

  ```
  gem 'postgres_ext'
  ```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I'm using SQLite and maybe these problems force me to move to PostgreSQL!! and the problem of your first solution is that it finds all the results that include the id. For example, if the id is 1, it finds 11, 13 and ... which are not true. Is there any helper such as LIKE to find the exact match?

Comment: @AboozarRajabi I've updated the custom query so that you won't get all those results. If it doesn't work look at how hash data is saved on your database and adjust accordingly. If your app is lightweight keep SQLite, otherwise PostgreSQL is a great DB.

Comment: @AboozarRajabi There it is again, I was missing the separators on the query - now it should work.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works well but I made a short edition. \n should be before % and also I've added serlization as another possible solution. Finally, could you please explain what is the difference between the current query and the first (shorter) one (with out including first, second, ... )??

Comment: @AboozarRajabi I'm glad it helped. I fixed the \n positions that were wrong on the query. Regarding the long version, it's just for better understanding and could be generalized for cases were `accessors` defined have nothing to do with each other, but in this case you could use a shorter version like `@persons = Person.where('friends LIKE ?', "%: #{@person.id}\n%")`. The serialization doesn't seem to help for this case since it's the same as using `store` - you'd run into similar problems. Remember to mark your correct answer and/or upvote posts that helped :)

Comment: @AboozarRajabi just for further explanation, a `store` can be used as a common **hash** like the ones you mentioned with `serialize`, doesn't matter which `accessors` you define. For instance, `@person.friends[:foo] = 'bar'` would work and would be stored on the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - You can't! Because, ActiveRecord stores your "hash" as a string in a single column. The only way I can think of is to use `.where("friends LIKE :friend", friend: 'BFF')` syntax. Don't forget to index your column though.

It is [mentioned in the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html) as well:

> It's like a simple key/value store baked into your record **when you don't care about being able to query that store** outside the context of a single record.

Comment: I thought when something like `friends.has_value?3` works fine in the rails console, it should be worked in the web app too! Ans is there any better way to implement a dynamic list like this? @Uzbekjon

Comment: It works in web app too. `.has_value?` is a [Hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-has_value-3F) method and it returns `boolean`. Your `friends` method returns hash. So it works just fine. But you can't give boolean to `.where` method. In your case, it ends up being: `Person.where(true)`.

Comment: My intention was to say something like `.where(boolean_attribute: true)` which works fine. I was looking for way to use my stored_attribute like this, but I have to use a method (like `has_value?`) with it to get the value and it makes the problem!!

Comment: Update the code in your question to reflect that. So, your `friends` method should be called on some instance of a model, right? So, use that instance there: `.where(boolean_attribute: current_user.friends.has_value?(3))`